# What is an antonym of 'editorial'?

Tags: vocabulary

An editorial means:

> A newspaper article written by or on behalf of an editor that gives an opinion on a topical issue.

I'd like to know a term that means:

> A newspaper article written by a news reporter that gives a factual account of an event.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., and in regards to newspapers:

- An "editorial" is an opinion piece or an expression of a particular ideology or point of view.  The purpose of an "editorial" is to promote an idea or belief.  Synonyms in regard to newspapers include "oped" and "column" (see below.)
- An "article" is a factual description of an event.  Synonyms in regard to newspapers include "story" and "report" (although "report" is more frequently used with visual news, such as CNN or your nightly news broadcast) and "column" (see below).
- A "column" can be either an "editorial" or an "article," usually written by a specific individual.  Columns are also usually recurring.

It is important to understand that this is almost entirely unique to *newspapers.*  How the words "editorial" and "article" are used in, for example, a monthly journal or magazine is different.  (Almost everything in a magazine is an "article," whether it's an opinion piece or not.)  However, "column" is used fairly consistently as I described in all printed medium.

Comment: Thanks. But as you can see, the very definition of 'editorial' is a newspaper article. So I was wondering if simply saying 'newspaper article' would necessarily exclude 'editorial'.

Comment: That's too basic, it's like saying that you can't use the word "Dalmatian" to describe a dog because it's still a "dog."  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/editorial) defines "editorial" as "a newspaper or magazine article that gives the opinions of the editors or publishers."  And, at least where I live, the answer is yes - saying "article" would exclude "editorials."

Answer (score 0):

Without any specification, "news **article**" or "newspaper **article**" refers to such a story by default.